# How to always have the same current directory in VIm and in Terminal?

Tags: unix, vim, vim-plugin

I would like to my terminal current directory follows my VIM one.

Example:

In TERMINAL:

```
> pwd
=> /Users/rege
> vim
```

Then in VIM

```
:cd /Users/rege/project
<Ctrl-z>(for suspend)
```

In terminal

```
> pwd
=> /Users/rege/project
```

I`m using MacOS, zsh, tmux.

I need this because when Im trying to use tags in VIM, tags are check in project from my terminal directory not vim one.

So I need to change terminal current directory always when I change VIM current directory.

Comment: What about `:shell`? It opens a new shell in Vim's current directory.

Comment: I explained this more clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What kind of command do you issue in your shell after you suspend Vim? Isn't Vim's `:!command` enough?

With `set autochdir`, Vim's current directory follows you as you jump from file to file. With this setting, a simple `:!ctags -R .` will always create a `tags` file in the directory of the current file.

Another useful setting is `set tags=./tags,tags;$HOME` which tells Vim to look for a `tags` file in the directory of the current file, then in the "current directory" and up and up until it reaches your `~/`. You might modify the endpoint to suit your needs. This allows you to use a `tags` at the root of your project while editing any file belonging to the project.

So, basically, you can go a long way without leaving Vim at all.

If you really *need* to go back to the shell to issue your commands, `:shell` (or `:sh`) launchs a new shell with Vim's current directory. When you are done, you only have to `$ exit` to go back to Vim:

```
$ pwd
/home/romainl
$ vim
:cd Projects
:sh
$ pwd
/home/romainl/Projects
$ exit
```

Answer (score 2):

In bash or zsh and on Unix you can do this: current working directory of the process is represented in `/proc/{PID}/cwd` as a symlink to a real directory. Speaking about zsh the following code will do the job:

```
function precmd()
{
    emulate -L zsh
    (( $#jobstates == 1 )) || return
    local -i PID=${${${(s.:.)${(v)jobstates[1]}}[3]}%\=*}
    cd $(readlink /proc/$PID/cwd)
}
```

. Note: with this code you won’t be able to pernamently switch directories in terminal anymore, only in vim or for duration of one command (using `cd other-dir && some command`).

Note 2: I have no idea how to express this in bash. The straightforward way is to get PIDs of all children of the shell (using `ps --ppid $$ -o CMD`), filter out the `ps` process (it will be shown as a child as well), check that there is only one other child and use its PID like in the last line above. But I am pretty sure there is a better way using some shell builtins like I did with zsh’s `$jobstates` associative array. I also don’t remember what is the analogue of `precmd` in bash.

---

Another idea would be making vim save its current directory into some file when you do `<C-z>` and make shell read this in precmd:

```
" In .vimrc:
function s:CtrlZ()
    call writefile([fnamemodify('.', ':p')], $CWDFILE, 'b')
    return "\<C-z>"
endfunction
nnoremap <expr> <C-z> <SID>CtrlZ()

# In .zshrc
function vim()
{
    local -x CWDFILE=~/.workdirs/$$
    test -d $CWDFILE:h || mkdir $CWDFILE:h
    vim $@
}
function precmd()
{
    local CWDFILE=~/.workdirs/$$
    test -e $CWDFILE && cd "$(cat $CWDFILE)"
}
```

. It should be easier to port above code to bash.

Comment: `/proc` is not available on Mac OS X. Your second idea looks good.

Comment: Look good but I would like to pin up this not on <C-z> but when I run in VIM ```:cd method```

Comment: @regedarek Why? It won’t change directory until you suspend vim in any case (shell does nothing when foreground process is running), running on `:cd` will just generate a bunch of useless writes.

Comment: TK !! I searched for so long ...
In bash PROMPT_COMMAND permits to change dir when comming back.
I am making an other answer (copyed from yours).

Answer (score 0):

you can open a new terminal like this

```
:!xterm -e bash -c "cd %:p:h;bash" &
```

actually I write this in my .vimrc

```
nmap <F3> :!xterm -e bash -c "cd %:p:h;bash" &<CR> | :redraw!
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is not what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

For bash users coming by:

**Vim:**  Save `pwd` at `<c-z>` (with `map` and `getpwd()`).
**Bash:** Before prompt command, goto directory indicated by vim with `PROMPT_COMMAND`.

**.bashrc**

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='read -r line 2>/dev/null </tmp/cd_vim'\
'&& > /tmp/cd_vim && cd ${line##\r};'$PROMPT_COMMAND
```

**vimrc**

```
function! s:CtrlZ() call writefile([getcwd(),''], '/tmp/cd_vim', 'b')
    return "\<C-z>"
endfunction
nnoremap <expr> <C-z> <SID>CtrlZ()
```

This is ZyX answer edited for bash https://stackoverflow.com/a/12241861/2544873